# Faster way to return bool matrix of points which are inside/outside of a curve, Python

Tags: python, image, vectorization, curve

I need, given a m*n image and a NURBS curve (geomdl package), to return a bool matrix with 0 if point (i,j) is outside given curve and 1 otherwise.

I managed to find a solution by approximating the curve by polygon and point by point determining wanted property using shapely.geometry package. My function:

```
def isInside(curve,m,n):
   coords=curve.evalpts
   polygon=Polygon(coords)
   points=np.zeros((m,n))
   for i in range(m):
       for j in range(n):
           points[i,j]=Point([i,j]).within(polygon)
   return points
```

This function is very slow (nested loop), I would like it to be much faster, due to how many times this function is called. I tried to "matrix-vectorized" it to avoid nested loop, but I couldn't find a working solution. Could anyone help with any idea?

Comment: What kind of performance are you seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Update: bug with extra points included fixed.

Late update with code that supports convex curves and generates more informative plots.

Solving this interesting problem is equivalent to fill-rasterizing a closed polygon.

This solution can handle any convex non-self-intersecting polygon of size limited only by available memory. **Note** that this algorithm considers all points **on** the polygon to be **inside** the polygon.

The code below produces several example plots (shown at the end of this answer) and demonstrates that the algorithm used is approximately 290 times faster than the code in the original question.

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Polygon, Point
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from math import pi, sin, cos, floor, ceil

def isInside2(curve, nx, ny):
    """ Returns a 2D numpy array which has ones inside
        the given curve and zeros outside.
    """
    curve = Polygon(curve)
    nparr = np.zeros((ny,nx))
    for y in range(ny):
        line =  LineString([(0,y), (nx,y)])  # This is the "scan" line.
        obj = curve.intersection(line)  # Shapely does the hard part!
        obj_type = obj.geom_type
        if obj.is_empty:
            pass
        elif obj_type == 'LineString':
            # Single horizontal line segment (x1, y) (x2,y)
            # We write 1's everywhere along the segment.
            (x1,_),(x2,_) = obj.coords
            i1, i2 = sorted((ceil(x1), floor(x2)))
            nparr[y,i1:i2+1] = 1
        elif obj_type == 'MultiLineString':
            # Like 'LineString' case above for each instance
            for linestring in obj.geoms:
                (x1,_),(x2,_) = linestring.coords
                i1, i2 = sorted((ceil(x1), floor(x2)))
                nparr[y,i1:i2+1] = 1
        elif obj_type == 'Point':
            nparr[y, int(obj.x)] = 1  # A single point
        elif obj_type == 'MultiPoint':
            for pnt in obj.geoms:
                nparr[y, int(pnt.x)] = 1
        elif obj_type == 'GeometryCollection':
            # Mix of points and lines
            for geom in obj.geoms:
                if  geom.geom_type == 'Point':
                    nparr[y, int(geom.x)] = 1
                else:
                    (x1,_),(x2,_) = geom.coords
                    i1, i2 = sorted((ceil(x1), floor(x2)))
                    nparr[y,i1:i2+1] = 1
        else:
            raise Exception('Unexpected obj_type:', obj_type)
    return nparr


############################################
#                 Examples                 #
############################################

def circle_poly(x, y, r, n):
    """ Helper function returns a circle centered at (x,y)i
        with radius "r" and "n" vertices """
    return [(x+r*cos(2*pi*i/n), y+r*sin(2*pi*i/n))  for i in range(n)]

#  Some examples
def plot_example(name, curve, array):
    """ Overlay the curve on the array """
    cmap = ListedColormap(['#777', '#000'])
    x,y = zip(*curve)
    plt.title(name)
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.imshow(array, origin='lower', cmap=cmap)
    plt.savefig(name)  # Save the plot
    plt.clf()

circle = circle_poly(500, 500, 400, 100)  # 100 segment circle
examples = [
    #  Name        nx      ny  curve
    ( 'Circle',  1000,   1000, circle ),
    ( 'Triangle1',  8,     13, ((1,1), (1,11), (6,6), (1,1)) ),
    ( 'Triangle2', 11,     13, ((1,1), (1,11), (10,6), (1,1)) ),
    ( 'Diamond',   13,     13, ((6,1), (1,6), (6,11), (11,6), (6,1))),
    ( 'Square',    13,     13, ((1,1), (1,11), (11,11), (11,1), (1,1))),
    ( 'Convex',    21,     21, ((0,0), (1,0), (6,9), (10,0), (14,4), (18,0),
                               (20,0), (20,3), (17,6), (17,8), (20,17),
                               (20,20), (11,20), (11,16),
                               (13, 16), (13, 12), (8,12), (8,16), (11,16),
                               (11,20), (5,20), (0,0))),
]
for example in examples:
    name, nx, ny, curve = example
    nparr = isInside2(curve, nx, ny)
    plot_example(name, curve,  nparr)

############################################
#              Performance                 #
############################################

from timeit import timeit

# Code in OP's question:
def isInside(curve,m,n):
    polygon = Polygon(curve)
    points=np.zeros((m,n))
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            points[i,j]=Point([i,j]).within(polygon)
    return points

def run(function, polygon):
    """ Time the given function (isInside or isInside2)
        with the given polygon """
    function(polygon, 1000, 1000)
globals()['run'] = run # Make "run" globally accessible

poly_K   = circle_poly(500, 500, 400, 1000)  #  1,000 segment circle
poly_10K = circle_poly(500, 500, 400, 10000) # 10.000 segment circle

print('Timing a 1,000 segment polygon...')
t_inside_K  = timeit(lambda: run(isInside,  poly_K),  number=5)
t_inside2_K = timeit(lambda: run(isInside2, poly_K),  number=5)
print(f'isInside took {t_inside_K:.3f} secs, isInside2 {t_inside2_K:.3f} secs'
      f' ({t_inside_K/t_inside2_K:.0f} times faster)')

print()
print('Timing a 10,000 segment polygon...')
t_inside_10K = timeit(lambda: run(isInside, poly_10K), number=5)
t_inside2_10K = timeit(lambda: run(isInside2, poly_10K), number=5)
print(f'isInside took {t_inside_10K:.3f} secs, isInside2 {t_inside2_10K:.3f} secs'
      f' ({t_inside_10K/t_inside2_10K:.0f} times faster)')
```

Outputs (after about 17 mins on my host):

```
Timing a 1,000 segment polygon...
isInside took 215.233 secs, isInside2 0.759 secs (283 times faster)

Timing a 10,000 segment polygon...
isInside took 1039.543 secs, isInside2 3.562 secs (292 times faster)
```

And generates the these example plots:

[image: Convex]
[image: Circle]
[image: Triangle1]
[image: Triangle2]
[image: Diamond]
[image: Square]